# How can I make all selector fields searchable when just typing in the selector (before opening the selector grid)?

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom screen with a selector that has 4 fields displayed when the selector is opened.  I am using the FastFilterFields property set to use all those fields, and that works fine.   What isn't working is typing in the field before the selector is open doesn't search ALL the fields - only the first field.

Is there a property to set to have all the fields searchable when typing in the selector field?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this

Comment: Yeah - I think you're right.  The only examples I can find in the stock Acumatica screens are when there is an ID and a description - but that's where the Selector has a 'DescriptionField' set, which probably allows the search to use that as well as the ID/CD...